# Is there any library for convolution reverb software for Visual Studio besides Freeverb?

Tags: convolution, software-implementation, c++

I am currently working on a simulation of a virtual scene. I calculate the IR of the direct path and the early reflections and want to convolute them with the input signal. My problem now is that implementing such a software for real-time purposes would exceed my time limit I got for my work. So I need a third party C++ library (my project is written in C++) for that.

I already tried Freeverb3 but did not get it to run using MinGW and FFTW as an additional third party software for Visual Studio. Is there any other free software besides Freeverb3 that can more easily be compiled and used than Freeverb?

I searched on this site as well as google for further software; but without success. Alternatively: Is there any way to get a convoluted input signal in real-time using convolution reverb libraries that I am not seeing? It kind of is a necessity for my project and any way possible is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You may find http://www.ludd.luth.se/~torger/brutefir.html helpful. And btw, Freeverb is an algorithmic reverb. You wouldn't have been able to use your calculated IR with it.

Comment: I googled for partitioned fft source code and found http://github.com/kverrier/Convolution

Comment: @Jazzmaniac Thank you. The link for BruteFIR states "...you will need a supported platform to run it on (Linux is recommended, but FreeBSD or Solaris should work out of the box too, it is not as closely maintained though)." Did you try it out on Windows for VS? Unfortunately I am bound to it. And I am kind of shocked that Freeverb is an algorithmic reverb. How comes? The website states under features: "Impulse Response Convolution Processor
Fast zero latency multithreaded algorithms optimized with SIMD."

Comment: @OlliNiemitalo I will definately try it out! Is it okay to just download projects of other people from git and use them?

Comment: If you don't distribute your software then it is OK but if you distribute it you need a license. Ask the owner for a license if you need it.

Comment: @Telefonica, checking out the Freeverb3 website I think you were right. It looks like they added arbitrary reverb IRs. Well, times change. Freeverb used to be a free implementation of a classical reverb algorithm.